# Publish android library to jcenter: gradle bintrayUpload does not find libraries

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I'm trying to publish an Android library to jcenter. I've followed https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish tutorial. Everything works fine until I try to execute

`gradle bintrayUpload`

When I do so I get a BUILD FAILED. When I look into the errors I see

`package com.android.volley does not exist`

Therefore the libraries that I have included as a gradle dependency are not being found

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+' (...)
}
```

The same happends with other libraries included.

How can I fix this problem?

I Attach the module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.bintray"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.3'
}

def siteUrl = "SOME_URL"
def gitUrl = 'SOME_URL'
group = "GROUP_ID"
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                // Add your description here
                name 'NAME'
                description = 'DESCRIPTION'
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'MY_ID'
                        name 'MY_NAME'
                        email 'MY_EMAIL'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

// https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        // it is the name that appears in bintray when logged
        name = "androidupdatechecker"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
        version {
            gpg {
                sign = true //Determines whether to GPG sign the files. The default is false
                passphrase = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password") //Optional. The passphrase for GPG signing'
            }
//            mavenCentralSync {
//                sync = true //Optional (true by default).     Determines whether to sync the version to Maven Central.
//                user = properties.getProperty("bintray.oss.user")         //OSS user token
//                password = properties.getProperty("bintray.oss.password") //OSS user password
//                close = '1' //Optional property. By default the staging repository is closed and artifacts are released to Maven Central. You can optionally turn this behaviour off (by puting 0 as value) and release the version manually.
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti files added

Comment: same issue here, i'll update if i find a solution. did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The library is in maven repository, so you need to declare the maven central repository. Add it in your project `build.gradle` file like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following:

```
  user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
  key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")
```

At this point, you need in your local. Join in the properties files,

```
Bintray. User = XXX
Bintray apikey = XXX
```