# publish my android aar to jcenter

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

I want to upload my android aar to the [bintray](https://bintray.com/).I reafer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655103/publish-android-library-to-jcenter-gradle-bintrayupload-does-not-find-libraries) ,but when I execute the cmd `#gradlew bintrayUpload`,the cmd show [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8ItX.png),and my gradle file as follow:

```
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty('bintray.user')
    key = properties.getProperty('bintray.apikey')
    configurations = ['published', 'archives']

    dryRun = false
    publish = true

    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'ActionAnimatorSet'

        desc = 'An animator operation set on Android'

        websiteUrl = 'https://github.com/paulyung541/ActionAnimatorSet'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/paulyung541/ActionAnimatorSet/issues'
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/paulyung541/ActionAnimatorSet.git'

        licenses = ['GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 3.0']
        labels = ['Android', 'ObjectAnimator', 'AnimatorSet']
        publicDownloadNumbers = true

        version {
            name = '1.0.0'
            desc = 'first version'
            vcsTag = '1.0'
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        Publication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.paulyung'
            artifactId 'actionanimset'
            version '1.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

I already setup a maven in bintray,but the cmd always point out that I don't have a maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at one of the following threads:
[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized when uploading binary on bintray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960614/http-1-1-401-unauthorized-when-uploading-binary-on-bintray)
[Trouble Publishing Android Studio Library on jCenter with Bintray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975279/trouble-publishing-android-studio-library-on-jcenter-with-bintray)

You might be missing the userOrg parameter.
It depends on if your maven repo resides under your organization or user.